# Order of a loop around a cone point

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a connected orientable two-dimensional orbifold with only cone points as singular points. Assume that $M$ has genus $\geq 1$. Let $\alpha$ be a loop around an order $p$ cone point. Can we conclude that $\alpha$ has order $p$ in the orbifold fundamental group $\pi_1^{\mathrm{orb}}(M)$?

Comment: This is correct yes. For instance, you can say that $M$ admits an orbifold metric with non-positive (actually negative if $p>1$) curvature thanks to uniformization. This tells you that $M$ is developable hence the local isotropy groups inject in the fundamental group. I imagine that there is probably a better, direct way to see this though.

Comment: @Henri: existence of a non-positively curved metric is much weaker than the full strength of uniformisation (which says that each conformal class of metrics contains a constant-curvature representative).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the answer is "yes" and there are many ways to see it. I would refer you to §2 of Peter Scott's survey paper "[The geometries of 3-manifolds](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgar/Teach/2021_3MFDS/References/1983the_geometries_of_three-manifolds.pdf)", in which he discusses 2-dimensional orbifolds. His Theorem 2.3 gives a complete list of *bad* orbifolds, i.e. orbifolds that are not developable. None of them are hyperbolic, so your orbifold $M$ is *good*, i.e. developable. This means that $M$ arises as a quotient $G\backslash S$, where $S$ is a surface, $G$ is the orbifold fundamental group, and the cone points correspond precisely to the orbits of points with non-trivial stabiliser. In particular, every cone point corresponds to an element in $G$ of the correct order.

Comment: In connection with the OP's hypothesis that $M$ has genus $\ge 1$, it is perhaps more relevant that the list of bad orbifolds has none of genus $\ge 1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: You're quite right. I had misremembered exactly what the OP had written.